# Foldr/Foldl for free when Tree is implementing Foldable foldMap?

Tags: haskell, fold, foldable

I am a beginner at Haskell and learning from "Learn You a Haskell".

There's something I don't understand about the `Tree` implementation of `Foldable`.

```
instance F.Foldable Tree where  
    foldMap f Empty = mempty  
    foldMap f (Node x l r) = F.foldMap f l `mappend`  
                             f x           `mappend`  
                             F.foldMap f r
```

Quote from LYAH: *"So if we just implement `foldMap` for some type,  **we get  `foldr` and `foldl` on that type for free**!"*.

Can someone explain this? I don't understand how and why do I get `foldr` and `foldl` for free now...

Comment: BTW, the mechanism for providing these free implementations is similar to the free implementation of `/=` you get if you implement `==` as discussed [here](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses#typeclasses-102)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

foldr can always be defined as:

```
foldr f z t = appEndo (foldMap (Endo . f) t) z
```

where appEndo and Endo are just newtype unwrappers/wrappers.  In fact, this code got pulled straight from the Foldable typeclass.  So, by defining foldMap, you automatically get foldr.

Comment: Similarly, `foldl` can be defined in terms of `foldr`, and hence also `foldMap`, so that function comes for free also.

Answer (score 31):

We begin with the type of `foldMap`:

```
foldMap :: (Foldable t, Monoid m) => (a -> m) -> t a -> m
```

`foldMap` works by mapping the `a -> m` function over the data structure and then running through it smashing the elements into a single accumulated value with `mappend`.

Next, we note that, given some type `b`, the `b -> b` functions form a monoid, with `(.)` as its binary operation (i.e. `mappend`) and `id` as the identity element (i.e. `mempty`. In case you haven't met it yet, `id` is defined as `id x = x`). If we were to specialise `foldMap` for that monoid, we would get the following type:

```
foldEndo :: Foldable t => (a -> (b -> b)) -> t a -> (b -> b)
```

(I called the function `foldEndo` because an endofunction is a function from one type to the same type.)

Now, if we look at the signature of the list `foldr`

```
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
```

we can see that `foldEndo` matches it, except for the generalisation to any `Foldable` and for some reordering of the arguments.

Before we get to an implementation, there is a technical complication in that `b -> b` can't be directly made an instance of `Monoid`. To solve that, we use the `Endo` newtype wrapper from `Data.Monoid` instead:

```
newtype Endo a = Endo { appEndo :: a -> a }

instance Monoid (Endo a) where
        mempty = Endo id
        Endo f `mappend` Endo g = Endo (f . g)
```

Written in terms of `Endo`, `foldEndo` is just specialised `foldMap`:

```
foldEndo :: Foldable t => (a -> Endo b) -> t a -> Endo b
```

So we will jump directly to `foldr`, and define it in terms of `foldMap`.

```
foldr :: Foldable t => (a -> b -> b) -> b -> t a -> b
foldr f z t = appEndo (foldMap (Endo . f) t) z
```

Which is the default definition [you can find in `Data.Foldable`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/src/Data-Foldable.html). The trickiest bit is probably `Endo . f`; if you have trouble with that, think of `f` not as a binary operator, but as a function of one argument with type `a -> (b -> b)`; we then wrap the resulting endofunction with `Endo`.

As for `foldl`, the derivation is essentially the same, except that we use a different monoid of endofunctions, with `flip (.)` as the binary operation (i.e. we compose the functions in the opposite direction).