# Explain how does new foldr work in Haskell

Tags: haskell

New Haskell programmer will soon enough go to sources to see how `foldr` is implemented. Well, the code used to be simple (don't expect newcomers to know about `OldList` or `FTP`).

How does the new code work?

```
-- | Map each element of the structure to a monoid,
-- and combine the results.
foldMap :: Monoid m => (a -> m) -> t a -> m
foldMap f = foldr (mappend . f) mempty

-- | Right-associative fold of a structure.
--
-- @'foldr' f z = 'Prelude.foldr' f z . 'toList'@
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> t a -> b
foldr f z t = appEndo (foldMap (Endo #. f) t) z
```

Comment: Probably not a duplicate, but [I wrote an answer on getting `foldr` from `foldMap` a while ago](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23319967/2751851). The answer presumes basic familiarity with `Monoid`, so please tell us if it takes too many things for granted.

Answer (score 11):

I'll just mention the parts that are *not* in [the answer @duplode linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23319683/foldr-foldl-for-free-when-tree-is-implementing-foldable-foldmap/23319967#23319967).

First, those implementations you list are *default* methods. Every `Foldable` type needs to provide its own specific version of at least *one* of them, and lists (`[]`) provide `foldr`, [which is implemented](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ghc/ghc/master/libraries/base/GHC/Base.hs) pretty much as it always has been:

```
foldr k z = go
          where
            go []     = z
            go (y:ys) = y `k` go ys
```

(Which is, for efficiency, a bit different from the Haskell report version.)

Also, a slight change in the `Foldable` default since duplode's answer is that strange `#.` operator, used internally in GHC's [`Data.Foldable`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.10.2/docs/html/libraries/base-4.8.1.0/src/Data-Foldable.html#line-447) code.  It's basically a more efficient version of `.` that works *only* when the left function is a newtype wrapper/unwrapper function.  It's defined using the new newtype coercion mechanism, and gets optimized into essentially nothing:

```
(#.) :: Coercible b c => (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> c)
(#.) _f = coerce
{-# INLINE (#.) #-}
```

Answer (score 0):

The mental model I have for foldr follows this structure:

> Given a list in it's a:(b:(c:[])) form, replace all ":" with the given
>   op (1st parameter), and then replace the "[]" with the given initial
>   value (2nd parameter).

A pseudo-codey example:

```
foldr (+) 0 [1,2,3,4] = 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 0
```

And remember, `[1,2,3,4]` is equivalent to `1:(2:(3:(4:[])))`