# Set of transformations f::a->a form a monoid over function composition - how do I make this an instance of Monoid?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, category-theory, monoids

It looks as though transformations should form a Monoid, with the identity function as the empty element and standard function composition as the binary operation. I don't think it's particularly useful, but it should be possible. Something along the lines of:

```
instance Monoid (a -> a) where
        mempty = id
        mappend f g = (.)
```

The above doesn't compile, possibly because it is masked by the pre-existing definition

```
instance Monoid b => Monoid (a -> b) where
    mempty _ = mempty
    mappend f g x = f x `mappend` g x
```

Error is:

```
Illegal instance declaration for ‘Monoid (a -> a)’
      (All instance types must be of the form (T a1 ... an)
       where a1 ... an are *distinct type variables*,
       and each type variable appears at most once in the instance head.
       Use FlexibleInstances if you want to disable this.)
    In the instance declaration for ‘Monoid (a -> a)’
```

I'm still a Haskell scrub so I'm not sure how I can fix this - any help?

Comment: As a footnote to the answers in the duplicate, one example of a nifty use of `Endo` is in [getting a default implementation for `foldr` out of `foldMap`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23319683/2751851).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the error message describes it quite well: `a -> a` is a too specific type:

> All instance types must be of the form `(T a1 ... an)`
>   where `a1 ... an` are *distinct type variables*,
>   and each type variable appears at most once in the instance head.

The `T` here is the function type `->`, you could've written without the special infix notation

```
instance Monoid ((->) a a) where …
```

and clearly `a` doesn't appear only once.

On how to can fix this, again the error message recommends

> Use [`FlexibleInstances`](https://prime.haskell.org/wiki/FlexibleInstances) if you want to disable this [restriction].

Comment: Or use `TypeFamilies` and write `instance a ~ b => Monoid (a -> b)`.