# How can I understand the laws for Foldable instances?

Tags: haskell

On the page describing Data.Foldable, it says:
Foldable instances are expected to satisfy the following laws:

```
foldr f z t = appEndo (foldMap (Endo . f) t ) z
foldl f z t = appEndo (getDual (foldMap (Dual . Endo . flip f) t)) z
fold = foldMap id
```

Please help me understand how the above laws work. What is `Endo . f`?

Comment: Related: [*Foldr/Foldl for free when Tree is implementing Foldable foldmap?*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23319683/2751851) (my answer there covers the same ground as kennytm's answer here, but tells the story in a somewhat different way.)

Answer (score 9):

[`Endo`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#t:Endo) is "the monoid of endomorphisms under composition". `appEndo` is the field of this type.

```
newtype Endo a = Endo { appEndo :: a -> a }

-- i.e.
Endo :: (a -> a) -> Endo a
appEndo :: Endo a -> (a -> a)
```

You may treat "[endomorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endomorphism)" as a technically-correct term of functions which input and output types are the same (`a -> a`).

`Endo` is an instance of `Monoid` with composition:

```
instance Monoid (Endo a) where
        mempty = Endo id
        Endo f `mappend` Endo g = Endo (f . g)
```

---

To make the law easier to grasp, let's use the List type as a concrete example:

```
instance Foldable [a] where
    foldMap f []     = mempty
    foldMap f (x:xs) = f x `mappend` foldMap f xs

-- i.e.
-- foldMap f [a, b, …, w] == f a `mappend` f b `mappend` … `mappend` f w
```

When we evaluate the RHS of the law:

```
   foldMap (Endo . f)         t
== foldMap (\x -> Endo (f x)) [a, b, …, w]
== (\x -> Endo (f x)) a `mappend`   …   `mappend` (\x -> Endo (f x)) w
== Endo (f a) `mappend` Endo (f b) `mappend`   …   `mappend` Endo (f w)
```

recall `mappend` for Endo is composition, so the above is

```
== Endo (f a . f b .   …   . f w)
```

Finally we use `appEndo (…) z` to take out the composed function and apply it to the initial value `z`:

```
   appEndo (Endo (f a . f b .   …   . f w)) z 
== (f a . f b .   …   . f w)                z
== f a (f b (  …  (f w z)  …  ))
```

and this is exactly the definition of `foldr` for a list.

---

The `foldl` one is similar, [`Dual`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#t:Dual) is another monoid instance where `` Dual a `mappend` Dual b == Dual (b `mappend` a) ``, and `getDual` takes out the inner monoid. It should be easy to see how this produces `foldl`.

---

The `fold` function collapses the foldable of monoids into a single monoid. Again using List as an example, `fold` can be implemented as

```
fold [a, b, …, w] == a `mappend` b `mappend` … `mappend` w
```

which can be retrieved from `foldMap`:

```
foldMap id [a, b, …, w] == id a `mappend` id b `mappend` … `mappend` id w
                        == a `mappend` b `mappend` … `mappend` w
```

this shows how the identity `fold = foldMap id` is suggested.

Comment: so `Endo a` is the set consisting of endo-maps from a to a?

Comment: @user28522 Yes, up to isomorphism. Note that in types, `Endo a` is the type of such maps, while in terms (programs/expressions) `Endo` is the name of the isomorphism `(a->a) -> Endo a`, while `appEndo` is its inverse iso.

Comment: I still don't understand:  "...... is the name of the isomorphism (a->a) -> Endo a, while appEndo is its inverse iso.". Please point me to the places where I can look up for more information to understand what you said. Thx.