# What does Traversable is to Applicative contexts mean?

Tags: haskell, applicative, monoids, traversable, foldable

I am trying to understand Traversable with the help of https://namc.in/2018-02-05-foldables-traversals.

Somewhere the author mentioned the following sentence:

> Traversable is to Applicative contexts what Foldable is to Monoid
>   values.

What did he try to clarify?

I do not get the connection between `Foldable to Monoid`.

Please provide an example.

Comment: I can't write a proper answer right now (will do it later if no one else covers it first). In the meantime, I wonder if you'll find the explanation in [the beginning of the Wikibook chapter](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Traversable#Functors_made_for_walking) (upon which this article was based on) any clearer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the beginning, there was `foldr`:

```
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
```

and there was `mapM`:

```
mapM :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> [a] -> m [b]
```

`foldr` was generalized to data types other than `[a]` by letting each type define its own definition of `foldr` to describe how to reduce it to a single value.

```
-- old foldr ::        (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [] a -> b
foldr :: Foldable t => (a -> b -> b) -> b -> t  a -> b
```

If you have a monoid, you don't have to specify a binary function, because the `Monoid` instance already provides its own starting value and knows how to combine two values, which is apparent from its default definition in terms of `foldr`:

```
-- If m is a monoid, it provides its own function of type b -> b.
foldMap :: (Foldable t, Monoid m) => (a -> m) -> t a -> m
foldMap f = foldr (mappend . f) mempty
```

`Traverse` does the same kind of generalization from lists to traversable types, but for `mapM`:

```
-- old mapM ::              Monad m        => (a -> m b) -> [] a -> m ([] b)
traverse :: (Traversable t, Applicative f) => (a -> f b) -> t  a -> f (t  b)
```

(When `mapM` was first defined, there was no `Applicative` class; if there had been, `mapA :: Applicative f => (a -> f b) -> [a] -> f [b]` could have been defined instead; the `Monad` constraint was stronger than was necessary.)

An `Applicative` is monoidal in nature, so there was no need in `Traverse` for the type of distinction that `foldr`/`foldMap` draws.

Comment: I think you have an extra slash in your first `foldr` signature.

Answer (score 0):

The article (and [the corresponding passage of the Wikibook](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Traversable#Functors_made_for_walking)) is talking about how the effects (or, to use the language seen there, the contexts) of applicative values can be combined monoidally. The connection with `Foldable` is that list-like folding ultimately amounts to combining values monoidally (see [chepner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55535649/2751851), and also [*Foldr/Foldl for free when Tree is implementing Foldable foldmap?*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23319967/2751851)). As for the applicative contexts part, there are a few ways to look at that. One of them is noting that, for any `Applicative f` and `Monoid m`, `f m` is a monoid, with `pure mempty` as `mempty` and `liftA2 mappend` as `mappend` ([the `Ap` type from `Data.Monoid`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.19.1.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#t:Ap) witnesses that). For a concrete example, let's pick `f ~ Maybe` and `m ~ ()`. That leaves us with four possible combinations:

```
liftA2 mappend (Just ()) (Just ()) = Just ()
liftA2 mappend (Just ()) Nothing   = Nothing
liftA2 mappend Nothing   (Just ()) = Nothing
liftA2 mappend Nothing   Nothing   = Nothing
```

Now contrast with [`All`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.19.1.0/docs/Data-Monoid.html#t:All), the `Bool` monoid with `(&&)` as `mappend`:

```
mappend (All True)  (All True)  = All True
mappend (All True)  (All False) = All False
mappend (All False) (All True)  = All False
mappend (All False) (All False) = All False
```

They match perfectly: `Just ()` corresponds to `True`, `Nothing` to `False`, and `liftA2 mappend` to `(&&)`.

Now let's have another look at the Wikibook example:

```
deleteIfNegative :: (Num a, Ord a) => a -> Maybe a
deleteIfNegative x = if x < 0 then Nothing else Just x

rejectWithNegatives :: (Num a, Ord a, Traversable t) => t a -> Maybe (t a)
rejectWithNegatives = traverse deleteIfNegative
```

```
ghci> rejectWithNegatives [2,4,8]
Just [2,4,8]
ghci> rejectWithNegatives [2,-4,8]
Nothing
```

The `Maybe` values generated by applying `deleteIfNegative` to the values in the lists are combined monoidally in the way shown above, so that we get a `Nothing` unless *all* the `Maybe` values are `Just`.

This matter can also be approached in the opposite direction. Through the `Applicative` instance for [`Const`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.19.1.0/docs/Data-Functor-Const.html#t:Const)...

```
-- I have suppressed a few implementation details from the instance used by GHC.
instance Monoid m => Applicative (Const m) where
    pure _ = Const mempty
    Const x <*> Const y = Const (x `mappend` y)
```

... we can get an `Applicative` out of any `Monoid`, such that `(<*>)` combines the monoidal values monoidally. That makes it possible to [define `foldMap` and friends in terms of `traverse`](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Traversable#Recovering_fmap_and_foldMap).

On a final note, the category theoretical description of `Applicative` as a class for monoidal functors involves something rather different from what I have covered here. For further discussion of this issue, and of other fine print, see [*Monoidal Functor is Applicative but where is the Monoid typeclass in the definition of Applicative?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50702929/2751851) (if you want to dig deeper, it is well worth it to read all of the answers there).